# Adding new values to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to add new values on my array in javascript. The array is like that:

```
[
  0: { Id: 0,
       Name: "First",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" },
  1: { Id: 1,
       Name: "Second",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" }
]
```

This is a simple array, my array is bigger and more values. I want to add new values like that:

```
[
  0: { Id: 0,
       Name: "First",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003",
       SecondTime: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" },
  1: { Id: 1,
       Name: "Second",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003",
       SecondTime: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003"  }
]
```

I know there are a lot of similar questions but i couldn't find any solution to my problem.

Comment: I tried make a new array which has one value, SecondTime and merge it. I failed.

Answer (score 2):

using `foreach`

```js
const data = [
   { Id: 0,
       Name: "First",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" },
{ Id: 1,
       Name: "Second",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" }
]

data.forEach(i=> i.SecondTime = i.Time);

console.log(data)
```

Using `reduce`:

```js
const data = [
   { Id: 0,
       Name: "First",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" },
{ Id: 1,
       Name: "Second",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" }
]

var res = data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
 elem.Secondtime = elem.Time;
 return acc = [...acc, elem];
},[]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

In an alternative to foreach and reduce answers, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Has you can see [here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2235/0/foreach-vs-reduce-vs-map-vs-filter-vs-for), for changing data, the map has a little better performance over foreach loops or reduce fucntions.

Follows a full working example:

```js
const originalArray = [
  { 0: { Id: 0,
       Name: "First",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" }},
  { 1: { Id: 1,
       Name: "Second",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003" }}
]

const transformedArray = originalArray.map((element, index) => {
  element[index].SecondTime = new Date();
  return element;
});

console.log(transformedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let blah = {
  0: { Id: 0,
       Name: "First",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003"},
  1: { Id: 1,
       Name: "Second",
       Time: "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003"  }
};

Object.keys(blah).forEach((ele)=>{
  blah[ele].SecondTime = "2020-06-08T11:12:03.003"
});

console.log(blah);
```

Hope this helps